# Why does my sum of a summed column in view multiplyes by 16?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, listagg

I want to make a sum over some criteria, but get a totally different result than expected. My setup is as follows:

First, I create a `view`. The important thing here is **item weights**, which are in table `aposition`. I have 1 order, 2 consignments and each consignment can have multiple items. Each item has weight. So, in the view I `sum` all item weights and partition them on **Order** level.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_view AS
SELECT orders.reference,
  sum(aposition.GEWICHTF) OVER (PARTITION BY consignment.ordernr) "Weight"
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN consignment ON orders.nr=consignment.ordernr
LEFT JOIN aposition ON aposition.consignmentNr=consignment.nr
WHERE orders.number>0
AND orders.inrecyclebin=0
AND orders.customernr=3450588;
```

This view gives me the following result:
[image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3z51.png)

```
reference | weight
1           24000
2           24000
```

All is fine until I try to SELECT the summed column and partition it on Invoice number:

```
SELECT distinct afaktura.fakturanr,
  (
    select listagg(t.n,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.n)
    FROM (
      select (UKV.aexternauftragsnr) n
      FROM test_view UKV
      where ukv.fakturanr=afaktura.fakturanr
    ) t
  ) "Reference Number",
  sum(test_view."Weight") OVER (PARTITION BY afaktura.fakturanr) "Weight"
FROM afaktura
LEFT JOIN test_view ON test_view.fakturanr = afaktura.fakturanr
LEFT JOIN calculation ON calculation.FK_IDAFAKTURA=afaktura.idafaktura
LEFT JOIN consignment ON consignment.nr=calculation.consignmentNr
LEFT JOIN aposition ON aposition.consignmentNr=consignment.nr
LEFT JOIN orders ON akopf.nr=consignment.ordernr
WHERE orders.number>0
AND orders.inrecyclebin=0
AND orders.customernr=3450588;
```

The result I get after the listagg of references and sum over the summed previously column is a couple of times higher. Should be 48000 instead of 384000: [image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bFpA.png)

```
reference | weight
1, 2        384000
```

The idea here is to have 1 invoice on 1 line, with references of all orders that this invoice includes and a sum of the weights of all those orders. The reason i am going through a view first is because it is a bit easier for me. I have more columns that need to be listed and since I am not good with SQL this is how I need to go about it.

Comment: Please format your code accordingly.

Comment: Hi, sorro. I always have problems with formatting those code snippets to appear normally.

Comment: The `distinct` is often a sign something is going wrong. I'd suggest you take that out and look at the number or rows being returned after all the joins - presumably some of those are matching multiple rows in child tables - either legitimately, or because you're missing part of a join condition. Without knowing your tables or data it could be either - you'll need to break your query down and debug it to see whether and where it is finding more rows than you expect; but you might need to rethink the approach too.

Comment: When your sum over a join is an exact muliple of the expected value, that might be an indication, that some rows are joined multiple times because your joining condition is not strict enough. And the necessity for a `distinct` is indicating the same. But it's hard to say any more without table structure and example data.

Comment: Yes, I found out why I get this. The view is wrong to begin with. The sum is almost correct. The issue is that the sum in the view is not on the correct level and when i do the next SELECT it sums all lines again.